# Phonegap - Android How to adjust layout in Full Screen Mode when softkeyboard is visible

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on an phonegap app for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. When this application is in full screen mode, the softkeyboard hides the text input fields and it's impossible to scroll the page to see the content.  how could I fix the problem?

Comment: I don't see a question in there...

Comment: George, you're right. Just added the question. I have to wait 8 hour to add my own anwser

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After spending a day trying almost every possible solution in this website, nothing worked for me. At the end I was able to find a work around based on the following two proposed solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494006/1435991

this link shows a workaround to fix the problem for an android app; however I don't have any experience working in android, so the question is: how to include this peace of code in a Phonepap project?.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18610405

This link suggests  specifically  a solution for phonegap, which did not work for me,  but more important gave an idea of how I could add custom android code on a phonegap project.

**SOLUTION**

1- Create the following class(as indicate in first link) in your phonegap project:

```
    package com.test.android;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    public class AndroidBug5497Workaround {
        // For more information, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497
        // To use this class, simply invoke assistActivity() on an Activity that already has its content view set.

        public static void assistActivity (Activity activity) {
            new AndroidBug5497Workaround(activity);
        }

        private View mChildOfContent;
        private int usableHeightPrevious;
        private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;

        private AndroidBug5497Workaround(Activity activity) {
            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            mChildOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
            mChildOfContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    possiblyResizeChildOfContent();
                }
            });
            frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mChildOfContent.getLayoutParams();
        }

        private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent() {
            int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
            if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious) {
                int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.getRootView().getHeight();
                int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;
                if (heightDifference > (usableHeightSansKeyboard/4)) {
                    // keyboard probably just became visible
                    frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference;
                } else {
                    // keyboard probably just became hidden
                    frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard;
                }
                mChildOfContent.requestLayout();
                usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
            }
        }

        private int computeUsableHeight() {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            mChildOfContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            return (r.bottom - r.top);
        }

}
```

This class can be placed in this location in your project: (I was not able to load an image in this forum, I need at lease 10 reputation). Find the image sample in this url:

[image: check for more clarity]

2- Any time you create a phonegap project you get a class called your_project_name.java. In my case it is test1.java. Edit the class and add the following sentence in method onCreate:

```
    AndroidBug5497Workaround.assistActivity(this);
```

Your code should look like this:

```
    public class test1 extends DroidGap
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set by  in config.xml
            super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
            //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
            AndroidBug5497Workaround.assistActivity(this);
        }
    }
```

3- This fixed the problem in my app.

Comment: Can confirm this code still works 2 years later on my OnePlus running 4.4.4 - Thank you so much!

Comment: I was supposed to use this fix for Cordova 6.0.0 and it still works like a charm. Is Cordova going to fix it or I have missed something?

Answer (score 3):

I Implemented Jorge's answer and it worked great for me!. but the screen resize itself in a bulky way, and i wanted it to resize more smoothly. So i looked up on how to animate this view and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11935216).

combining the two together looks like this:

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class AdjustInputHeight {

    // For more information, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497
    // To use this class, simply invoke assistActivity() on an Activity that already has its content view set.

    public static void assistActivity (Activity activity) {
        new AdjustInputHeight(activity);
    }

    private View mChildOfContent;
    private int usableHeightPrevious;
    private ValueAnimator animateCollapseView = null;
    private ValueAnimator animateExpandView = null;
    private boolean keyboardIsUp = false;
    DecelerateInterpolator sDecelerator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;

    private AdjustInputHeight(Activity activity) {
        FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        mChildOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
        mChildOfContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                possiblyResizeChildOfContent();
            }
        });
        frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mChildOfContent.getLayoutParams();
    }

    private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent() {
        int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
        if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious) {
            int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.getRootView().getHeight();
            int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;

            //check if the view got smaller (because keyboard is shown) and is not already up.
            if (heightDifference > (usableHeightSansKeyboard/4) && (!this.keyboardIsUp)) {

                // we need to create the collapse animator the only the first time we rise the keyboard
                if (this.animateCollapseView == null) {
                    this.animateCollapseView = ValueAnimator.ofInt(usableHeightSansKeyboard, (usableHeightSansKeyboard-heightDifference));
                    this.animateCollapseView.setDuration(500);
                    this.animateCollapseView.setInterpolator(sDecelerator);
                    this.animateCollapseView.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                            frameLayoutParams.height = value.intValue();
                            mChildOfContent.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                }

                this.animateCollapseView.start();
                // keyboard probably just became visible        
                this.keyboardIsUp = true;

            //lower the keyboard only if it is up.  
            } else if (this.keyboardIsUp) {

                // we need to create the expand animator the only the first time we lower the keyboard
                if (this.animateExpandView == null) {   
                    this.animateExpandView = ValueAnimator.ofInt((usableHeightSansKeyboard-heightDifference), usableHeightSansKeyboard);
                    this.animateExpandView.setDuration(200);
                    this.animateExpandView.setInterpolator(sDecelerator);
                    this.animateExpandView.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                            frameLayoutParams.height = value.intValue();
                            mChildOfContent.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                }

                this.animateExpandView.start();
                // keyboard probably just became hidden
                this.keyboardIsUp = false;
            }

            usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
        }
    }

    private int computeUsableHeight() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        mChildOfContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        return (r.bottom - r.top);
    }
```

}

of course you can change the animation duration and interpolator for your own needs.

Comment: good idea but does not works if you have to inputtext in the same view